# Will API Management automatically switch over to disaster discovery site that outside of configured region?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I have deployed API Management in EU region and what happens when EU region goes down?
Will API Management automatically switch over to disaster discovery site other regions?
Can we control/specify an EU data recovery center?

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by configuring a Secondary region if you are using the Premium tier.

Please find information about regions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region

> An API Management gateway component is deployed to every selected Primary and Secondary region. Incoming API requests are automatically directed to the closest region. If a region goes offline, the API requests will be automatically routed around the failed region to the next closest gateway.

> Only the gateway component of API Management is deployed to all regions. The service management component and developer portal are hosted in the Primary region only. Therefore, in case of the Primary region outage, access to the developer portal and ability to change configuration (e.g. adding APIs, applying policies) will be impaired until the Primary region comes back online. While the Primary region is offline, available Secondary regions will continue to serve the API traffic using the latest configuration available to them. Optionally enable zone redundancy to improve the availability and resiliency of the Primary or Secondary regions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but in case I only use primary region and do not use secondary region before. What happen when EU region goes down ?  APIM will witch to default region ?

Comment: What is a default region? I never heard about such a thing.

Comment: Let me explain a little bit. In case, I only use primary region and not configure for other regions. I just want to know when primary region goes down, what happens ? what will API Management do at that time ?

Comment: There are also [availability zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/migrate-api-mgt) for the premium tier. If you do not choose the [premium tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features) your API Management will not work if it is down in your region